# Is there a way to fix MCC tool chest world converter's rendering glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

MCC tool chest is a program I used to convert my bedrock edition world to Java edition.

After I played a while, I realized that only the amount I discovered in my bedrock world renders in and the rest is a bunch of messed-up glitched blocks.

It is a survival world, so I want to keep exploring.

My two final questions are: Is it possible to make the whole bedrock world go into Java edition? 
                            Is it possible to make the world render in properly in Java?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you sure "rest is a bunch of messed-up glitched blocks" as opposed to their being a one-time cliff at the boundraies and then more working terrain on the other side?

Comment: That did not happen in this world.  Are you sure that the generation is normal after a wall? For me, it didn't seem that normal... I'll have to double-check. Thank you for a tip though.

Comment: Yeah, this is caused by Java generating new chunks on a completely different seed to the bedrock world. Those chunks shouldn't be glitched out at all, though.

Answer (score 2):

Bedrock and Java edition has different chunk generation, so you could find something like this:
[image]
After you cross "border of your bedrock world" generation will be normal, but for java edition - it can't generate your old bedrock anymore, even with same seed.
There is a small chance, that you put your world somehow to amplified version, but unlikely. It would look like [this](https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/minecraft_gamepedia/c/c8/AmplifiedWorldMojang.jpg?version=db1056cfbc5f79261afec11725a831ee) and [this](https://i.redd.it/fshh05i6kqm41.png).